# Validation message for file upload control in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

when i upload file in mvc3 project i need validation for sicze limit and user only upload image, doc and xls file. should be there like required field, wrong selection of file, size limitation in asp.net mvc3

Comment: Are you using jQuery file upload? What code you have written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I use the Telerik uploader control and I set this as the method that runs when the file is selected but it can be used with a standard file uploader as well

```
function onSelect(e) {
    if (e.files[0].size > 256000) {
        alert('The file size is too large for upload');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    // Array with information about the uploaded files
    var files = e.files;
    var ext = $('#logo').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'tif', 'pdf']) == -1) {
        alert('This type of file is restricted from being uploaded due to security reasons');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Basically, it says if the file is over 256k it's too big and will only allow gif, jpeg, jpg, png, tif and pdf files...